# Remove transparent white background from gif image using glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

How can I remove white background around image when loading with glide.. You can find out below code as well as screenshot;

```
  Glide.with(thiscontext).load(R.drawable.badge_green_yellow)
 .asGif().crossFade()
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(holder.ivHourlyIcon);
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: I think your image has the white background, and you can not set transparency.

Comment: if the image itself has that background, then Glide has nothing to do with it. And it looks like that is the image. Edit the image, and remove the background from it

Comment: Actually There is no white background behind this gif image

Comment: and it does not show always....sometimes it changes behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your GIF into the raw folder (res/raw/badge_green_yellow.gif)

and then load it like this

```
Glide.with(thiscontext).asGif().load(R.raw.badge_green_yellow).into(holder.ivHourlyIcon);
```

Comment: Can you tell me that whats a diff when get gif from drawable and raw folder

Comment: first tell me difference

Comment: I have faced same issue few days earlier and resolved it by putting in raw folder. When you put your gif under drawable the android OS treat it as JPG images and hence make a white background