# Android - Glide adds white background to a gif with transparent background

Tags: android, animation, loading, gif, android-glide

I am developing a custom loading dialog that will be used in every activities of the Android app.
The gif has transparent background, but when I load it with de Glide library it adds a white background. This is the code:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/custom_loading_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading_image_animation"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewDialog class, it's called from every activities:

```
public class ViewDialog {
    Activity activity;
    Dialog dialog;

    public ViewDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        dialog  = new Dialog(activity);
        //dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //...set cancelable false so that it's never get hidden
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        //...that's the layout i told you will inflate later
        //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_loading_layout);
        RelativeLayout contentView = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) activity)
                .getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_loading_layout, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        final ImageView image = (ImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.loading_image_animation);
        

        Glide.with(activity).asGif().load(R.raw.wannaplay_loading).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE).into(image);
        dialog.show();
    }

    //..also create a method which will hide the dialog when some work is done
    public void hideDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks, it shouldn't have the white background
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92jKj.png)

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54104986/4981406

Comment: @sajjad I have already tried it, it didn't work. The fig is in the raw folder but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure it's not your `dialog`/`layout` background? You may try it outside the `dialog` and make sure.

Comment: @sajjad my dialog/layout doesn't have any background. I tried adding 
`contentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` or `contentView.setBackgroundResource(0);`
but it's the same

Comment: <ImageView
android:background="@android:color/transparent"  
        android:id="@+id/loading_image_animation"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

Comment: @sajjad I've just tried to load the gif in an activity without dialog and it worked well. Do you know how can I remove correctly that white background from dialog? Because I need it to show it in every activities, not just in one of it

Comment: @kzncrda That doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've just figure it out. I removed the white background adding this line in my ViewDialog class

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```